# Set a specific color to a bubble chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, colors, bubble-chart

I would like to set a specific color on the circle of bubble chart in terms of a variable. I can change all the bubble in red for example but not each bubble. My condition is an attribute of d and it define by the content of my JSON.

```
node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.size; })
        .style("fill", "red"); // all my bubble are red but the condition doesn't works
        /* 
        if (condition) {
          .style("fill", "red");
        } else {
          .style("fill","green");
        }
        */
```

This is the Plunker project : https://plnkr.co/edit/07RZFQoBrBz2xWxmiCl0?p=preview
Thanks.

Comment: the plunkr you gave already changes the color of the circles depending on their size with it's style callback =>.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.size); });

Comment: Please, explain what's the condition to fill the circles.

Comment: I update the plunker, you can check now. The condition si the content of size attribute         `node.append("circle")
                .attr("r", function(d) { return d.size; })
                .style("fill", "red")
                if (d.size==1){
                  // .style("fill","green")
                } else if (d.size==2){
                   // .style("fill","orange")
                } else if(d.size==3)){
                   // .style("fill","blue")
                }`

Comment: I just answered. Once your values (1, 2, 3 etc) for the `d.size` are too small, I made an answer with bigger sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
.style("fill", function(d){
              if (d.size <= 20){
                return "green"
              } else if (d.size <= 40){
                return "orange"
              } else if (d.size <= 70){
                return "blue"
              } else {
                return "red"
              }
            });
```

I wrote `<=` just to get some intervals, but you can change this the way you want. And using `else if` you can set any number of conditions you want.

Here is the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Q2reQnEFTcL58xNseYXl?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The reason your condition code not working is it break the chaining, like:

```
d3.select(selector)
.attr()
.style()
.append()
```

You can use condition while keep chaining by this:

```
.style("fill", condition ? "red" : "green")
```

If the condition is more than two, for both functionality and readability, we create a function.

```
function color(condition) {
  switch (expression) {
    case redCondition:
      return "red"
      break;
    case blueCondition:
      return "blue"
      break;  
    default:
      return "green"
  }
}

.style("fill", color(condition))
```

Comment: How can I do if I want to have more than two conditions ?

Answer (score 0):

To write this for any number of conditions, you can use a [threshold scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#threshold-scales). Just like we use scales to map data values to x and y values, we can use a scale to convert from a number to a color.

A threshold scale maps values to a *discrete* range, and map subsets of the domain to these discrete values:

```
colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([20, 40, 70])
    .range(["green", "orange", "blue", "red"]);
```

Because of how `scaleThreshold()` works, you need one more value in the range than in your domain to achieve the expected effect. Think of it like values with ticks: everything in-between is the desired color. If you're on a tick exactly, then it'll convert to the next color, so `colorScale(20) === "orange"`.

```
green | orange | blue | red 
      20       40     70
```

```js
var colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([20, 40, 70])
    .range(["green", "orange", "blue", "red"]);

console.log('colorScale(0):', colorScale(0))
console.log('colorScale(20):', colorScale(20))
console.log('colorScale(30):', colorScale(30))
console.log('colorScale(60):', colorScale(60))
console.log('colorScale(70):', colorScale(70))
console.log('colorScale(100):', colorScale(100))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```